# Unix - simple Calculator using shell scripting [edited]

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I just start to write a simple script using shell in Unix OS, I tried to write a simple calculator the code first, the code let the user choose an operation (addition, Subtraction, etc) it will be saved as a variable (choose) then, let the user insert any two numbers those numbers will be saved as variables (num1 and num2) finally, perform the operation, check the code for further info

```
echo "+--------------------+"
echo "| Simple Calculator  |"
echo "+--------------------+"
echo "This shell is a simple calculator that takes two numbers from user, perform math operation then return the results"
echo Please choose an operation from the following:
echo 1,Addition
echo 2,Subtraction
echo 3,Multiplication
echo 4,division
echo Please choose an operation
read choice
echo Please insert the 1st number:
read num1
echo Please insert the 2ed number:
read num2
case $choice
1) echo "The result of addition operation is:`expr $num1 + $num2`;;
2) echo The result of Subtraction operation is:`expr $num1 - $num2`;;
3) echo The result of Multiplication operation is:`expr $num1 \* $num2`;;
4) echo The result of Division operation is:`expr $num1 \/ $num2`;;
*) echo invalid operation, please try again;;
esac
```

unfortunately, the code still not working even though I made some changes it keep showing this error:

./shell.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `1'
./shell.sh: line 16:`1) echo The result of addition operation is: `expr $num1 + $num2`;;'

Note: This code is not for a university project nor a homework just me exploring and learning.

Answer (score 1):

Your `case` syntax is wrong.

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html

explains how to use `case`; since what you want to do is not becoming clear from your source code, I can't really give you much information on how to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

For fun:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Better calculator"
while read -r -p 'Enter expression (CTRL-C or CTRL-D for end)> ' exp
do
    echo "$exp =" $(bc -l <<< "$exp")
done
```

or just enter to command prompt:

```
bc -l
```

But probably your teacher want something different... :)

Answer (score 0):

So I know my mistake now :D

my mistake was in line 15 I should've put 'in' after chose

"case $choose in" --> this is very important when you use "case"

simple right! --> this made me crazy for a while "^__^

Answer (score 0):

```bash
echo "+--------------------+"
echo "| Simple Calculator  |"
echo "+--------------------+"
echo "This shell is a simple calculator that takes two numbers from user, perform math operation then return the results"
echo Please choose an operation from the following:
echo 1,Addition
echo 2,Subtraction
echo 3,Multiplication
echo 4,division
echo Please choose an operation
read choice
echo Please insert the 1st number:
read num1
echo Please insert the 2ed number:
read num2
case $choice
1) echo "The result of addition operation is:`expr $num1 + $num2`;;
2) echo The result of Subtraction operation is:`expr $num1 - $num2`;;
3) echo The result of Multiplication operation is:`expr $num1 \* $num2`;;
4) echo The result of Division operation is:`expr $num1 \/ $num2`;;
*) echo invalid operation, please try again;;
esac
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!